# react-router transition to new page with different query string parameter

Tags: query-string, react-router

I have the following code in a file that initializes my react router:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename:CONFIG.baseName})

<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path={"/list/:propertyType"} component={Leasing} />
<Route path={"/list/:propertyType?city=:city"} component={Leasing} />
</Router>
```

On my webpage, I have some links like

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'
... some code
<Link to="/list/office" />
<Link to="/list/retail" />
<Link to="/list/retail?city=Washington" />
```

When I go from the page `/list/office` to `/list/retail`, my webpage will reload data.  But the problem is that the page will not reload data when I go from `/list/retail` to `/list/retail?city=Washington` .

How do I make clicks on links that have the same url portion but different query string portion to cause the browser to render new content?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when I go from `/list/office` to `/list/retail`, both the functions `render()` and `componentDidMount()` fires.  But when I go from `/list/retail` to `/list/retail?city=Washington`, only `render()` fires and `componentDidMount()` does NOT fire.

So basically any content that I was loading via ajax in the `componentDidMount()` was not being recognized when only the query parameters of a url was changing.